# Tool/proceedure to remove Shimano direct mount rim brake bearings (Ultegra in this case)

Tags: road-bike, brakes, mechanical, rim-brake

Looking for some advice on what tool I need/the process to remove the pivot bearings from the Shimano Ultegra direct mount rim brakes. It looks like I'll need a hook wrench(?) to get at the rear silver nuts, but the black notched ring on the front I'm unsure of .

Note this is not a question of how to remove the caliper from the frame - I want to remove the sleeve that the silver bolt sits inside.

Reason for asking is one side feels gritty and a little tight.

EDIT:
I suspect this answers my question: https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-BR-R8010-RS-4254.pdf

The parts I'm referring to are not explicitly listed so I doubt are meant to be serviced.

[image: front view]

[image: side view]

Comment: I don't know - would a cone spanner help ?

Comment: This is a guess but it looks suspiciously like it takes TL-ST01. They're only a few dollars.

Comment: @Criggie unfortunately there are no flat sides to lock onto - I tried a set of needle nose pliers and an some mole grips but wasn't having any luck.

Comment: @NathanKnutson never even heard of that tool before but it looks promising, and is cheap enough to be worth a shot. Now to find one.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably leave them alone unless you have a lot of confidence in yourself as a mechanic. Those are the brake posts that are pressed (not threaded) in at the factory, and serve as the brake mounting posts (since the frame doesn't have posts).

If you **must** disassemble these, you can watch a video of someone with very shaky hands pulling a slightly earlier generation of direct mount brake apart here:

[Shimano Direct Mount Rear Brake Repair and Mods Tutorial Guide How To DIY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Om4UyeoNpuw)

You'll have to make a couple of tools yourself, and if you're lucky, you won't scratch up the caliper or accidentally break any of the parts. The caliper posts aren't sealed at all, so if this is a chainstay-mounted break, it's likely that a bunch of grit got in there and is making the post/brake body interface gritty.

This newer generation of brake may also be flange-riveted at the back of the brake body, meaning it's a one-way fit; once disassembled, it will not fit back together properly at all.

Answer (score 1):

Shimano does not offer a tool to service the brake-bearings.
Maybe it helps to see how i fixed the problem:
https://forum.tour-magazin.de/showthread.php?268301-Der-quot-heute-hab-ich-geschraubt-quot-Thread&p=6421341#post6421341

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/52283)